# Using AInputQueue_attachLooper() in a native library

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk

I need to handle events from the acceleration sensor and the hard keys in my native library.
I've implemented for the sensor and that works fine:

```
looper = ALooper_forThread();
if (looper == NULL)
    looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);

sensorManager = ASensorManager_getInstance();
accSensor = ASensorManager_getDefaultSensor(sensorManager,
        ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
if (accSensor == NULL)
    LOGE("get Default Sensor");

sensorEventQueue = ASensorManager_createEventQueue(sensorManager, looper,
LOOPER_ID, get_sensor_events, NULL);

if (ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor(sensorEventQueue, accSensor) < 0)
    LOGE("Enable sensor");

ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate(sensorEventQueue, accSensor,
        (1000L / SAMP_PER_SEC) * 1000);
```

However for the hard keys I'm missing an InputQueue to do the same trick:

```
looper = ALooper_forThread();
if (looper == NULL)
    looper = ALooper_prepare(ALOOPER_PREPARE_ALLOW_NON_CALLBACKS);
AInputQueue_attachLooper(inputQueue, looper, LOOPER_ID, get_input_events, NULL);
```

One solution would be to read the event file directly in my case `/dev/input/event3`, but I don't have the right permissions. I could change the permissions in the init.rc file, but as the event number could change, I don't think it's the right solution. I couldn't find a way for the kernel driver to set the permissions when it creates the input device.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the native activity, you might want to implement onInputQueueCreated callback:

```
static void OnInputQueueCreated (ANativeActivity* activity, AInputQueue* queue)
```

*queue* param will hold the pointer to the input queue you are looking for.